# PDI: Simultaneous Unwind of two arrays from MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pdi

Within Spoon I have used the mongoDB Input step. for a given document of form..

```
{"Number": [
    "4700100004"
],
"Random": [
    "unknown"
],
"List_Of_Vals1": [
    "3",
    "2",
    "1",
],
"List_Of_Vals2": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
]}
```

I am able to unwind one of the arrays using Mongo query from pdi

```
[{"$unwind":"$List_Of_Vals1"}]
```

which produces::

```
Number       Random    List_Of_Vals1    List_Of_Vals2
"4700100004" "unknown" "3"              ["1","2","3"]
"4700100004" "unknown" "2"              ["1","2","3"]
"4700100004" "unknown" "1"              ["1","2","3"]
```

But ultimately I need to unwind both arrays sequentially which I thought I might be able to do by writing

```
[{"$unwind":"$List_Of_Vals1"},{"$unwind":"$List_Of_Vals2"}]
```

but this returns a duplication of "List_Of_Vals1"

```
Number       Random    List_Of_Vals1    List_Of_Vals2
"4700100004" "unknown" "3"              "1"
"4700100004" "unknown" "3"              "2"
"4700100004" "unknown" "3"              "3"
...
...
...
```

What I cant seem to figure out how to get is both unwound without duplication as such:

```
Number       Random    List_Of_Vals1    List_Of_Vals2
"4700100004" "unknown" "3"              "1"
"4700100004" "unknown" "2"              "2"
"4700100004" "unknown" "1"              "3"
```

Any Help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) option for `$unwind` introduced in Mongo 3.2 to achieve this. For each document outputted by the `$unwind` operation, it adds a new field holding the array index.

You can use these fields in `$project` and `$match` stages to filter the output to the correct subset of documents, i.e. those where the indexes match.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$List_Of_Vals1", includeArrayIndex : "index1" } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$List_Of_Vals2", includeArrayIndex : "index2" } },
  { $project: { 
         _id : 1,
         Number: 1,
         Random: 1,
         List_Of_Vals1: 1,
         List_Of_Vals2: 1,
         valid: { $eq: ["$index1", "$index2"] } }
   },
  { $match: { valid: true } } 
]);
```

Note that unwinding 2 arrays of size `n` will produce `n x n` results so you may run into problems with limits if both arrays can be large.

There is an upcoming feature for a [$zip operator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20163) that should enable a better solution.